# Image with src "/_next/static/media/..." has legacy prop "layout". Did you forget to run the codemod?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have this code

```
<div className={`w-5 h-5 relative flex-shrink-0 ${additionalClasses}`}>
    <Image src={icon} layout="fill"/>
</div>
```

I am getting this in the console

[image: console log image]

I was not expecting anything warning in console

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since NextJs 13 introduced new `Image` component, prop `layout` has been deprecated. If you want to make your image fill the parent, just use `fill`. Consult with [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#fill)

```
<div className={`w-5 h-5 relative flex-shrink-0 ${additionalClasses}`}>
    <Image src={icon} fill/>
</div>
```